# stop all async Task when they fails over threshold?

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency, scala-cats, monix

I'm using [*Monix*](https://monix.io/docs/3x/) `Task` for async control.

### scenario

1. tasks are executed in parallel
2. if failure occurs over X times
3. stop all tasks that are not yet in complete status (as quick as better)

### my solution

I come up the ideas that race between 1. result and 2. error counter, and cancel the loser.
Via `Task.race` if the error-counter get to threshold first, then the tasks would be canceled by `Task.race`.

### experiment

on [*Ammonite*](https://ammonite.io/) REPL

```
{
  import $ivy.`io.monix::monix:3.1.0`
  import monix.eval.Task
  import monix.execution.atomic.Atomic
  import scala.concurrent.duration._
  import monix.execution.Scheduler
  //import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global
  implicit val s = Scheduler.fixedPool("race", 2) // pool size

  val taskSize = 100
  val errCounter = Atomic(0)
  val threshold = 3

  val tasks = (1 to taskSize).map(_ => Task.sleep(100.millis).map(_ => errCounter.increment()))
  val guard = Task(f"stop because too many error: ${errCounter.get()}")
    .restartUntil(_ => errCounter.get() >= threshold)

  val race = Task
    .race(guard, Task.gather(tasks))
    .runToFuture
    .onComplete { case x => println(x); println(f"completed task: ${errCounter.get()}") }
}
```

---

### issue

The outcome is depends on thread pool size !?

**For pool size 1**
the outcome is almost always a task success i.e. no stop.

```
Success(Right(.........))
completed task: 100 // all task success !
```

**For pool size 2**
it is very un-deterministic between success and failure and the cancelling is not accurate.
for example:

```
Success(Left(stop because too many error: 1))
completed task: 98
```

the canceling is as late as 98 tasks has completed.
the error count is weird small to threshold.

The default global scheduler get this same outcome behavior.

**For pool size 200**
it is more deterministic and the stopping is earlier thus more accurate in sense that less task was completed.

```
Success(Left(stop because too many error: 2))
completed task: 8
```

the larger of the pool size the better.

---

If I change `Task.gather` to `Task.sequence` execution, all issues disappeared!

---

What is the cause for this dependency on pool size ?
How to improve it or is there better alternative for stopping tasks once too many error occurs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing is likely an effect of the monix scheduler and how it aims for fairness. It's a fairly complex topic but the documentation and scaladocs are excellent (see: https://monix.io/docs/3x/execution/scheduler.html#execution-model)

When you have only one thread (or few) it takes a while until the "guard" Task gets another turn to check. With `Task.gather` you start 100 tasks at once, so the scheduler is very busy and the "guard" cannot check again until the other tasks are already done.
If you have one thread per task the scheduler cannot guarantee fairness and therefore the "guard" unfairly checks much more frequently and can finish sooner.

If you use `Task.sequence` those 100 tasks are executed sequentially, which is why the "guard" task gets much more opportunities to finish as soon as needed. If you want to keep your code the way it is, you could use `Task.gatherN(parallelism = 4)` which will limit the parallelism and therefore allow your "guard" to check more often (a middleground between `Task.sequence` and `Task.gather`).

It seems a bit like Go code to me (using `Task.race` like Go's `select`) and you're also using side-effects unconstrained which further complicates understanding what's going on. I've tried to rewrite your program in a way that's more idiomatic and for complicated concurrency I usually reach for streams like `Observable`:

```scala
import cats.effect.concurrent.Ref
import monix.eval.Task
import monix.execution.Scheduler
import monix.reactive.Observable

import scala.concurrent.duration._

object ErrorThresholdDemo extends App {

  //import monix.execution.Scheduler.Implicits.global
  implicit val s: Scheduler = Scheduler.fixedPool("race", 2) // pool size

  val taskSize  = 100
  val threshold = 30

  val program = for {
    errCounter <- Ref[Task].of(0)

    tasks = (1 to taskSize).map(n => Task.sleep(100.millis).flatMap(_ => errCounter.update(_ + (n % 2))))

    tasksFinishedCount <- Observable
      .fromIterable(tasks)
      .mapParallelUnordered(parallelism = 4) { task =>
        task
      }
      .takeUntilEval(errCounter.get.restartUntil(_ >= threshold))
      .map(_ => 1)
      .sumL

    errorCount <- errCounter.get
    _          <- Task(println(f"completed tasks: $tasksFinishedCount, errors: $errorCount"))
  } yield ()

  program.runSyncUnsafe()
}
```

As you can see I no longer use global mutable side-effects but instead `Ref` which interally also uses `Atomic` but provides a functional api which we can use with `Task`.
For demonstration purposes I also changed the threshold to 30 and only every other task will "error". So the expected output is always around `completed tasks: 60, errors: 30` no matter the thread-pool size.

I'm still using polling with `errCounter.get.restartUntil(_ >= threshold)` which might burn a bit too much CPU for my taste but it's close to your original idea and works well.

Usually I don't create a list of tasks up front but instead throw the inputs into the Observable and create the tasks inside of `.mapParallelUnordered`. This code keeps your list which is why there is no real mapping involved (it already contains tasks).

You can choose your desired parallelism much like with `Task.gatherN` which is pretty nice imo.

Let me know if anything is still unclear :)

Comment: cool, I never known that Observable can be useful in these case.  
Is that work like sliding a sequence and stop it at some point.
Comparing to race, I guess it might be more controllable than thread pool's queue.

Comment: It works because Tasks are lazy and Observable does backpressure the stream. So when you have 100 tasks but stop the stream early (e.g. using ".take(50)"), then it will also stop earlier steps of the stream without processing them (whether it's exactly at 50 depends on parallelism).

Here's a small demo I wrote to show backpressure in action (just change some of the numbers and see how it changes the behavior): https://scastie.scala-lang.org/felixbr/AWcjn0JvS52bVFY4FLleuA/16